# Joomla 3.x onContentAfterSave not triggering

Tags: joomla

my over all goal is to grab the articles content after they have saved it and send it though my API. It's stated that onContentAfterSave is fired after they save to the database, my database is getting updated, but nothing coming though api.

Im using Joomla! 3.2.3 Stable
Owtest is my api call, it currently has hard coded data in it.
I feel im either extending the wrong class or missing an import. code below.

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');


class plgContentHelloworld extends JPlugin
{
  public function onContentAfterSave( $context, &$article, $isNew  ) 
  {
    owTest();

   }

 }
?>
```

Xml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="2.5" type="plugin" group="content" method="upgrade">
     <name>plg_content_helloworld</name>
    <author>Keith</author>
    <creationDate>March 18th, 2014</creationDate>
    <copyright></copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License</license>
    <authorEmail></authorEmail>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <files>
            <filename plugin="helloworld">helloworld.php</filename>
            <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

file names are helloworld.php and helloworld.xml respectfully.

Comment: This could be for to a variety if reasons.  Can you post the plugin manifest xml file?  Is that the actual test method you're using which you posted?  Curious as that should throw an error.  Speaking of, was there anything logged in your PHP error logs?

Comment: What is owTest? try to raise an exception there or error_log or add a breakpoint if you have a debugger handy. As @BrianBolli suggested, post the manifest and tell us the files and folder names.

Comment: added it to orginal post. that is all my code right there, what you see is what im testing out. owtest is a function with static content in it right now basically its the api call to my website. (that code words and been tested).

Comment: i started this project and used public function onContentAfterTitle($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart)
        {
                return "<p>Hello World!</p>";
        }

 and that worked fine all i did was replace the method name and instead of return hello world told it to call my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what solved my problem was passing article by value and not reference